# Remove zip code from braintree ios SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, payment, braintree

I am using braintree ios sdk for my iPhone app. I do not need zip code in payment form. How can I disable/remove the zip field?

Comment: You can get the sources of this SDK from GitHub (https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios), make needed changes and then use your own customized version of SDK.

Comment: Ok, @SergeyNikitin , I am trying modify it.

Comment: In this case, It's not necessary to modify the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the headers file for [`BTPaymentFormView`](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_ios/blob/master/braintree/BTPayment/BTPaymentFormView.h#L46). There is a boolean property that you can set to change whether or not the zip code field is included:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL requestsZip; // default is YES
```

If you are not using Venmo Touch and just creating a custom credit card form, it should be as simple as:

```
BTPaymentFormView *paymentForm = [BTPaymentFormView paymentFormView];
[paymentForm setRequestsZip:NO]];
```